# Does a vanishing Integral of $fg$ for all $f$ imply $g=0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

I'm currently studying unbounded operators on hilbert spaces and wanted to show that the multiplication operator 
$$
T: D(T) \subset L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to  L^2(\mathbb{R})
$$$$
f(t) \mapsto tf(t)
$$
is self-adjoint. There i was faced with the following problem:
If $$
\int (fg)(t) dt = 0 \quad \forall f\in D(T), $$
$D(T)$ being dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, can i say that $g=0$ almost everywhere, even though $g$ is not necesseraliy in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$? Sure, if $g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ would hold i could just argue with the scalar product but that's basically what i want to prove. Am i just missing something?

EDIT: Here the situation:

$$ \int f(t)(tg(t)-h(t)) = 0 \quad \forall f\in D(T), $$
Here $g,h \in  L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and i want to show that $tg(t) = h(t)$ so that $tg(t) \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. $D(T)$ is defined as the space of all $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ that satisfy: $tf(t) \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Take the function $g(x)$ with $g(x)=1, x=0$ and $g(x)=0, x\ne 0$

Comment: Ok, maybe i should add "$g=0$ almost everywhere", i'll edit that in.

Comment: $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is already quotiented by the equivalence relation ($f \sim g$ iff $f=g$ almost everywhere}). So implicitely $g=0$ means $g=0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Is $g$ any measurable function or does it have some known properties ?

Comment: If $f$ is the characteristic function of a bounded measurable set, then $f \in D(T)$, right?  So, what if you take that measurable set to be $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \mathrm{Re}(g(x)) > 0 \} \cap [-N, N]$ for example?

Comment: I edited the whole situation in the post, maybe that helps, too. And yeah, i wanted to make sure with the 'almost everywhere' that everyone's on the same page (since $g$ is not in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and so on...)

Comment: Oh, or the standard trick of $f(x) := \overline{\mathrm{sgn}(g(x))} \chi_{[-N, N]}(x)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Oh, that seems nice. Didn't know about this extension of the sign-function. Thanks!